# In node, how do I detect how much time is left in a redis session?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

In node using express.js, I have a redis-based session set up thusly:

```
// Redis session
const sessionStore = new RedisStore({
    client: getRedisClient(),
    prefix: 'bl:',
    ttl: parseInt(config.sessionTTL, 10),
    logErrors: (err) => {
        log.error('Redis session error', {
            err_message: err.message,
            err_stack: err.stack
        });
    }
});

app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

The ttl parameter is typically set to 30 minutes, at the end of which the session dies quite nicely.

I now need to advise the user when 5 minutes or less remains of their session but can't find a way of determining when I hit that landmark.

I assumed (rather naively) the amount of time left would be stored in req.session, but when I display that it typically only shows the following:

```
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
  cookieChoiceConfirmationBannerSeen: 'seen',
  accessPage: '/decision/application-reference',
  appRef: '12345678'
}
```

How can I find how much time is left on my session? Should I use maxAge or expiry rather than ttl?

========= EDIT =========
Additial info:
the code for getRedisClient:

```
const redis = require('ioredis');
const config = require('../config/config');

let client;

const getRedisClient = () => {
    if (!client) {
        client = redis.createClient({
            host: config.redisHost,
            port: config.redisPort
        });
    }
    return client;
};

module.exports = {
    getRedisClient
};
```

Comment: Are you are using this lib https://github.com/tj/connect-redis?

Comment: Yes.
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
& redis client -> 
const { getRedisClient } = require('./app/services/redis-client');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the ttl of the entry itself by calling your redisClient with the corresponding key, i.e. your defined key-prefix (default `sess`) and the session-id. Something like this should work:

```
const prefix = 'bl:';
 
const redisClient = getRedisClient();

// Redis session
const sessionStore = new RedisStore({
  client: redisClient,
  prefix: 'bl:',
  ttl: parseInt(config.sessionTTL, 10),
  logErrors: (err) => {
    log.error('Redis session error', {
        err_message: err.message,
        err_stack: err.stack
    });
  }
});

app.get('/get-session-ttl', (req, res) => {    
    redisClient.ttl(`${prefix}${req.session.id}`,((err, reply) => {
        console.log("the remaining ttl is "+reply);
        res.send("...");
    }));
})
```

Comment: So, based on the above, I added the following piece of middleware to my app:
```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    sessionStore.ttl(`prefix:${req.session.id}`,((err, reply) => {
        console.log("the remaining ttl is "+reply);
        next();
    }));
});
```
This gave me the following error:
```
TypeError: sessionStore.ttl is not a function
```

So I tried:
```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(sessionStore.ttl);
  next();
});
```
which worked but showed sessionStore as always 1200 and never decrementing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need call ttl on the redisClient instance not the sessionStore. Basically change your code to keep a reference to the redisClient, see my edit.

Comment: Almost there! I substituted the app.get to an app.use so the code gets called every time I go to a new page. And I swapped res.send for next(). However, the value of reply is always -2.
                      
                     (Sorry for being thick. I suspect there's something blindingly obvious I'm missing.)

Comment: I've added the code for my redis setup to my OP, just in case it's relevent.

Comment: Yes! I changed the prefix constant from 'bl:' to 'bl' and we have lift-off! Thanks for saving my sanity!